# Add css filters dynamicaly via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, filter, slider

I'm trying to add several css filters dynamicaly via Jquery.

So I have one slider for the brightness and another one for the contrast.

I want them both to modify a single div.

I can easily do this with one filter but I got some difficulties getting the value of both sliders and apply them on this single div.

I tried this, but the behaviour is odd

**HTML :**

```
<input class="brightness" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100">
<input class="saturation" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100">
<div></div>
```

**Jquery :**

```
$('input').change(function(){

    var $brightness_value = $('.brightness').val(),
        $saturation_value = $('.contrast').val(),
        $brightness_string = "brightness("+$brightness_value+"%)",
        $saturation_string = "saturate("+$saturation_value+")";


    $('div').css("-webkit-filter",$brightness_string+$saturation_string);
});
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You have a typo: `$('.brighness')` is missing the `t`. Is that in the real code or just a copying error?

Comment: Sadly just a copying error

Comment: you're trying to do this? http://jsfiddle.net/DYjw8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to put the `%` to the value of saturate :

```
$saturation_string = "saturate("+$saturation_value+"%)";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DYjw8/3/